# Error:Connection Failed Z1

Tags: tizen

My Tizen idea shows my device in connection explorer and its selected too, but when I tried to launch app it gives error:

> There is no target to launch. Please select an emulator or a device in
>   Connection Explorer.

sdb connect to failed although sdb device shows my device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable debugging mode. After tht only you will be able to see your device in tizen sdk device window.

Instructions to enable USB Debugging mode

- Go into Menu and select Settings
- Press to Home button to return to the homescreen
- Click the Green Dial icon
- Type * # 84 936 # – The numbers 84936 actually spell out TIZEN
- Select Icon on Right Hand Side to enable Developer Option
- Press Home button to return to home screen
- Press and hold Home button to bring up recent apps
- Swipe across on the Settings App to close it
- Press Home button to return to the home screen
- Go into Menu and select Settings (again)
- Scroll to the bottom and select Developer Options
- Select the icon next to USB Debugging

For more info check this link

http://www.tizenexperts.com/2015/01/developer-enable-developer-usb-debugging-mode-tizen-samsung-z1-sm-z130hds/

Comment: @ehsan-haq :Could you please check whether after following my answer, your  problem was fixed or not?